# How to remove faux fireplace?

Tags: fireplace, demolition

I am interested in removing the faux fireplace in my living room and replacing it with one more in the right style for my house.  I didn't own the house when it was installed, so I'm not sure if it's one big piece, or how it is actually attached.  I think the top is enameled cast iron and the rest is brickwork.  Has anybody else dealt with this?  Although it is not to my taste it is in good condition so ideally I would like to remove it without damaging it so I could sell it to a local restoration shop.  The surrounding walls are plaster, so there is the additional concern of any heavy demo causing collateral damage.

[image]

Comment: If you check your chimney location does it match the fireplace? Any chance this was once a working fireplace that was blocked off?

Comment: Nope, the chimney is nowhere near this.

Comment: It looks like it was designed for an electric 'fireplace'? Weird. Anyways, to remove it, go get a mallet/hammer and start whacking at it.

Comment: ha! oops. Missed the 'want to keep it in good condition'. I'd go to the restoration shop and ask them this. Some will even come and take it out for you.